# Insert new numbered directory between sequentially numbered directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to insert a new directory into a list of already created directories. For example, if I have the following list of subdirectories:

`00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13`

I would like to insert a new subdirectory named `04` and move the rest of them up by one:

`00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14`

Obviously I can't move the old `04` to `05`, because there is already a directory named that. The list of subdirectories always starts at `00`, can end anywhere up to `99` (no fixed number of directories), and there are never any missing subdirectories (i.e. `01 02 03 05` never occurs). I would love to do this all with a bash script if at all possible; if not I'll take any help I can get!

Comment: Copy paste of a response you'll certainly receive - 
It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: That being said, a good place to start would be experimenting on your own and seeing where you can get. Logically, this will require you to decipher the highest numbered directory, work backwards to your desired addition, moving the directories and files as you go.  Take a stab at it and SO will be here to help if you get stuck.  `find` and `mv` are good tools to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could tackle it with straight Bash, no external commands (except `mv`):

```
#!/bin/bash

newdir=$1

# Put all directories into array
dirs=(*/)

# Remove trailing "/" from each array element
dirs=("${dirs[@]/%\/}")

# Get index of last directory
lastidx=$(( ${#dirs[@]} - 1 ))

# Loop over directories, starting with last, down to the one with the same
# name as the one being inserted
# Use 10# to force decimal instead of octal interpretation of name
for (( idx = lastidx; idx >= 10#$newdir; --idx )); do
    # New name of directory is current name plus 1
    # Again 10# to avoid confusion because of leading zeros interpreted as
    # octal values
    printf -v newname '%02d' "$(( 10#${dirs[idx]} + 1 ))"
    echo "Renaming ${dirs[idx]} to $newname"
    mv "${dirs[idx]}" "$newname"
done
```

For an existing directory structure like

```
.
├── 00
├── 01
├── 02
├── 03
├── 04
├── 05
├── 06
├── 07
├── 08
├── 09
├── 10
├── 11
├── 12
└── 13
```

you could use it like

```
$ ./insertdir 04
Renaming 13 to 14                
Renaming 12 to 13                
Renaming 11 to 12                
Renaming 10 to 11                
Renaming 09 to 10                
Renaming 08 to 09                
Renaming 07 to 08                
Renaming 06 to 07                
Renaming 05 to 06                
Renaming 04 to 05
```

and end up with

```
.
├── 00
├── 01
├── 02
├── 03
├── 05
├── 06
├── 07
├── 08
├── 09
├── 10
├── 11
├── 12
├── 13
└── 14
```

i.e., the script doesn't really insert anything – it makes room for the new directory.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `./insert.sh: line 21: 10#test: value too great for base (error token is "10#test")`; line 21 is     `printf -v newname '%02d' "$(( 10#${dirs[idx]} + 1 ))"`

Comment: @captainalright You seem to have a directory named `test`. The script expects only two-digit numbers as directory names.

Comment: That was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Its not to hard if you let yourself use a couple commands. 
I came up with this which I think is a decent way to do it, but there are a thousand other ways to do it

```
function insert_folder() {

    local insert=$(echo $1 | sed -E 's/0([0-9])/\1/')

   `# Find all of the folders that match the pattern`            \
    find . -iregex "./[0-9][0-9]" -exec basename {} \;           \
   `# Remove leading 0's for now since it confuses bash`         \
    | sed -E 's/0([0-9])/\1/'                                    \
   `# Sort the folders largest to smallest (prevent collisions)` \
    |sort -rn                                                    \
   `# For each folder mv if greater than instert value`          \
    | xargs -I {} bash -c "
          if [ {} -ge ${insert} ]; then 
              mv \$(printf '%02d' {}) \$(printf '%02d' \$(({}+1))); 
          fi
    " 
    mkdir $1
}


find . -type f
> ./00/00.txt
> ./01/01.txt
> ./02/02.txt
> ./03/03.txt
> ./04/04.txt
> ./05/05.txt
> ./08/08.txt
> ./09/09.txt
> ./10/10.txt
> ./11/11.txt

insert_folder 05
find . \( -type f -or -name 05 \)  
> ./00/00.txt                          
> ./01/01.txt                          
> ./02/02.txt                          
> ./03/03.txt                                                           
> ./04/04.txt                          
> ./05
> ./06/05.txt                          
> ./09/08.txt                          
> ./10/09.txt                          
> ./11/10.txt                          
> ./12/11.txt                          
> ./13/12.txt
```

Comment: When I attempt this I get this error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'`

Comment: There cant be any whitespace after the trialing backslashes. Backslash newline escapes the newline and means the command continues to a new line. backslash whitespace new line just escapes the whitespace and the command will end at the new line, which is probably what you are seeing.